# How to determine library name by jar

Tags: jar

In my web application, I am using 3td party jar files. To make an Attributions Document I need to group the jar files specifying its library name. My question is about how can I found the library name of used jars or any tool that I can upload jars and it will group jars by library? I looked at them in a maven repository but there is no information about library name. 
Here is the list of jar files:

```
serializer.jar
ant-1.10.3.jar
avalon-framework-api-4.3.1.jar
barcode4j-2.1.jar
batik.jar
batik-awt-util-1.9.1.jar
batik-xml-1.9.1.jar
bcel-6.2.jar
common-core.jar
commons-beanutils-1.9.3.jar
commons-dbcp-1.4.jar
commons-vfs2-2.2.jar
derby-10.14.2.0.jar
eigenbase-properties.jar
eigenbase-resgen.jar
eigenbase-xom.jar
fluent-hc-4.3.3.jar
fop-2.2.jar
freemarker.jar
groovy-all-2.4.13.jar
gson-2.2.2.jar
httpclient-4.5.5.jar
httpclient-cache-4.5.5.jar
httpcore-4.4.9.jar
httpmime-4.5.5.jar
jboss-logging-3.1.3.GA.jar
jkeylockmanager-1.0.0.jar
joda-time-2.2.jar
jsonassert-1.2.0.jar
log4j-1.2.17.jar
olap4j-1.2.0.jar
poi-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar
velocity-1.7-dep.jar
xalan-2.7.2.jar
xbean.jar
xercesImpl-2.11.0.SP5.jar
xml-apis-1.3.03.jar
xml-apis-ext.jar
xmlbeans-2.3.0.jar
xmlgraphics-commons-1.4.jar
xpp3.jar
olap4j-jdk14.jar
dom4j-1.6.1.jar
jsch-0.1.51.jar
retroweaver-rt.jar
xmlunit.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
mail.jar
jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar
activation.jar
jmxremote_optional.jar
jaxb-api.jar
saaj-api.jar
saaj-ri.jar
jsf-api.jar
junit-4.10.jar
pivot4j-core-0.9.jar
jrcerom.jar
keycodeDecoder.jar
pfjgraphics.jar
QueryBuilder.jar
webreporting.jar
webreporting-jsf.jar
XMLConnector.jar
mondrian-3.14.0.0-12.jar
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
aspectjrt-1.8.9.jar
aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar
jdt-compiler-3.1.1.jar
jflex-1.4.3.jar
rhino-1.7R3.jar
mysql-connector-java-5.1.25-bin.jar
icu4j.jar
jasperreports-5.5.0.jar
javadbf-0.4.0.jar
jcommon-1.0.15.jar
jxl-2.6.10.jar
png-encoder-1.5.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.5.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.3.8.Final.jar
jcifs-1.3.17.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.7.1.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar
jsoup-1.9.1.jar
iText-2.1.7.js2.jar
itext-rtf-2.1.7.jar
javassist-3.18.1-GA.jar
Access_JDBC30.jar
Excel_JDBC30.jar
jpa.jar
jpivot.jar
```

Comment: what do you mean by library name? normally a `jar` is identified by its groupId, artifactId, and its version. do you mean groupId?

Comment: For example Apache POI library consist of follwoing jars: 

poi-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
commons-collections4.jar